# twitter api trends swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter

Developing a twitter connect app and getting the trends with the url:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/closest.json?lat=42&long=36
```

> Output:

```
[
   {
    "name": "Turkey",
    "placeType":  {
      "code": 12,
      "name": "Country"
    },
    "url": "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/23424969",
    "parentid": 1,
    "country": "Turkey",
    "woeid": 23424969,
    "countryCode": "TR"
  }
]
```

How can i get the actual content of the trends? Hope there are some solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to call

> GET trends/place

not trends/closest you have everything in api documentation

[documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place)